# Bump map textures vs texture wrapping through UV mapping

Tags: modeling, uv, texture-baking

I'm currently sculpting an organic model of a dragon and was just wondering for the scale and skin details, can I not just use bump maps and vertex colouring instead of texture wrapping the model?

Also last question, I'm currently adding details on to the 'multi-res' modification of the model, if I wanted to keep the skin details but get rid of the multi-res, would I just bake the multi-res onto a lower poly version of the model?

Comment: Uh, let's take this sentence: "can I not just use bump maps and vertex colouring instead of texture wrapping the model?". Bump Map is a map, meaning a texture, right? You'll need some kind of UVs for that, even if auto-generated. For a very organic mesh, like a dragon, I doubt that an auto-gen UV-layout would do, but it depends of what you want to achieve. I mean, it is hard to judge what you want without any visual reference.
If you have multiple questions, please threat them separatelly.

Comment: oh sorry I meant alpha textures instead of bump maps, I'm assuming it still doesn't matter in this case? also will do!